# accessing array inside array php laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have an array $data['result'] ,and I can access it by `$data['result']` , I want to access the array inside the result array called items and then again the items array inside that items array. Please help. [image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data['result']` is a `LengthAwarePaginator`.

The first `items` child is a `Collection` representing the slice of data being paginated.

The `items` in the `Collection` is the array of items represented by the `Collection`.

You can access this array from the paginator using the `items()` method.

```
$collectionItems = $data['result']->items();
```

Comment: can you tell me how to empty that items and assign another array variable,

Comment: @Rox You will need to ask another question, showing any relevant code and what you'd like to do.

Comment: please help me , $data['result']->items() have some array , which i want to clear and i have another array which I want to assign to $['result']->items()